# Is this use of polymorphism misleading and therefore bad design?

Tags: ruby, interface, polymorphism, duck-typing

If I have the following ruby module which implements a particular interface (`apply` in this case)

```
module FooApplier
  def apply
    foo
  end
end
```

...and all other "Appliers" are classes, not modules, is it misleading to other engineers to pass `FooApplier` to receivers which expect the `apply`interface?

Let's assume the application using `FooApplier` runs perfectly fine, but let's also assume that some other engineer didn't take the time to pour over every last byte of my code. If they decide to send something like `.new` to the `FooApplier` which somehow induces some subtle bug, is the onus on my design, or the engineer for making assumptions and neglecting to read my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your module is presented here, it won't work as a stand-in for a class. Let's look at a class first:

```
class BarApplier
  def apply
    bar
  end
end
```

`apply` here is an instance method, so callable on instances of `BarApplier`, i.e. `BarApplier.new.apply`. This will not be possible for your module.

Unless of course `apply` was meant to be a class or module method, in which case your question was misleading since it then should be `def self.apply`.

But to answer the more general question, in a duck-typed language the sent messages **are** the interface. In my opinion the caller should make no assumptions about other methods being present. In your specific case, if `apply` is the only method in the "contract", assuming that the same entity also responds to `new` is invalid in my opinion.